# Is there way to keep the old data in SQL Server for long 10 years?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, database-performance

I am working on a software app that stores a large amount of data in SQL Databases. One Database for Online with live transactions and another reporting database that stores the archived data from an online database.  There is a migration thread that constantly copies the transactions from online to report databases.

The online database is purged often to keep only limited data and report database having the data for a longer period.

One of the recent requests is that keep the data for 10 years in the reporting database, but it will definitely affect the reporting queries performance.

I was thinking to have a PurgedRecords Table for each table in reporting db, that stores the purged records and keep the limited data on actual tables. I am not an expert in SQL, but I am thinking there should be some better methods to do it. Another option is to use the replicated report database without purging.

Please share your thoughts.

SQL Server 2019 Standard/Enterprise
Application Side: C#.NET Windows Services. .NET 4.8

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on [table partitions](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/)

Comment: Define "large amount of data". How many rows (average) per year? How much storage space required per row?

Answer (score 1):

> One of the recent requests is that keep the data for 10 years in the reporting database, but it will definitely affect the reporting queries performance.

Not if your database is architected properly. Size of data at rest has no impact on performance if you design and implement your database efficiently.

B-Tree indexes have `O(log(n))` search time complexity, which is very fast. Columnstore indexes are also very fast for aggregative and columnar type of queries. Despite Stu's comment, partitioning the table itself is rarely needed since indexes already *partition* the data for you, in a much more efficient way, than linearly like partitioning does.

Provide your Table, Index, and Query definitions with their actual execution plans if you're looking for more specific advice.

Long story short, don't try to over-optimize too early until you encounter and fully understand what your root performance issue is. I say this with experience from working with "*big data*", on modest hardware, and sub-second query times.